# Rotating only one feature of a point layer

Tags: qgis

I am working on a gas network utility and I create some point layers in order to insert some symbols of special forms. However, each symbol should be attached the network with a specific angle in order to fit it with the network. Rotating actions applies to all point symbols of the layer. Is it possible to rotate only one feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have an attribute that gives you the rotation angle for each feature you can use that to rotate the symbol that is displayed.

In the styling panel look for `Rotation` and click the edit button at the right handside. When the Expression editor comes up just type in the name of your attribute (surrounded by `"`).

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this tip. Ok, I have to extract the angles of the gaz network touching the point symbols and then use these angles as field in the table attribute of symbols to allow rotation with the appropriate values